# Inserting combobox via code

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I'm trying to insert a drop-down list that has a "PASS/FAIL" criterion to the right of a cell that the user populates. The cells will be populated from top to bottom in order. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub ComboBoxPassFail()      
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    i = 4

    For Each c In Worksheets("Inspection Report").Range("A4", Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Cells
        If c.Value <> "" Then

        Set rng = c.Offset(0, 14)

        Top = rng.Top
        Left = rng.Left

        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="forms.combobox.1", Left:=Left, Top:=Top, Width:=8, Height:=15).Insert

        i = i + 1

        End If
    Next c

    i = 4

End Sub
```

My main problem comes from dealing with comboboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things

1. `top` and `left` are reserved words in VBA. You cannot use them as variables
2. Since you are working with Excel rows, declare row as `Long` and not `Integer`. BTW I do not see the use of `i` in the code.
3. `.Insert` is not valid statement.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub ComboBoxPassFail()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim rngTop As Double, rngLeft As Double

    For Each c In Worksheets("Inspection Report").Range("A4", Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Cells
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            Set rng = c.Offset(0, 14)
            rngTop = rng.Top
            rngLeft = rng.Left

            '~~> You may want to decide on a more appropriate width value? :)
            ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add classtype:="forms.combobox.1", _
                                       Left:=rngLeft, Top:=rngTop, _
                                       Width:=8, Height:=15
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Regarding the width, I thought it goes by points, not pixels. I just checked the column width and took the points value. It was corrected. As for the left, and top, I had corrected those after i submitted the question here. The i was meant to be there for a different way of doing it and i forgot to take it out. Either way, I managed to add them now. Will work on inserting the "PASS", "FAIL" criterion. Thanks!